# Displaying currently connected Bluetooth device name

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

```
if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device1 : bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
        if (device1.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
        // Display the name of the currently connected device
        device=device1;
        }
    }
updateUI(device.getName(), "Connected");
```

I am trying to get the name of currently connected device via bluetooth.
But in the code its showing a different device name not the correct device name.

Comment: Provide more information